# How to add a set to a list of Sets in Scala

Tags: scala, list, set

I have a list of Sets and would like to add a Set to it. My assumption would be that I have to add to a list using the `::` [operator](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-add-elements-to-a-list-in-scala-listbuffer-immutable).

My code:

```
// attribute_sets is a tuple (String, Set[String])

val listsOfSets: List[Set[String]] = attribute_sets
      .foldLeft(List[Set[String]])((acc, attribute_set) => {
        acc  :: (attribute_set._2 + attribute_set._1)
      })
```

IntelliJ tells that there is a type mismatch (`expected String, actual Set[String]`), when I try to add to `acc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::` only to add an element at the beginning of a list:

```
x :: list
```

To add something at the end of the list, you have to use the `:+` operator:

```
list :+ x
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it.

Comment: @User12547645 however be aware that `:+` has **O(N)** complexity _(where N is the size of the list)_ - `List` is intended to be build by prepending objects, not to append to them... if the order matters to you, one common approach is to build the list backwards and then reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `attribute_set._2 + attribute_set._1` is `String`, since the `+` operation used is the one of `String`.

Hence the `::` operation cannot resolve, since it's used to concatenate sets, not to add a String to a Set.

So you either have to change the `+` or the `::` operator depending on the actual result you expect.